# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) when jQuery ajax post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form and when user enters some value in a text field i want to autofill other fields, but it keeps returning SystemStackError (stack level too deep). This are the files:

routes.rb

```
scope :places, controller: :places, as: :places do
    post :postcode, action: :postcode, as: :postcode
end
```

form.html.erb

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="input_postcode">
    <input type="text" class="input_state">
</form>
```

main.js

```
$(document).on('change', ".input_postcode", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var postcode = $(this).val();
    $.post( 'places/postcode', { postcode: postcode }, function(data) {
        $(".input_state").val(data.state);
        return false;
    }, 'json');
    return false;
});
```

places_controller.rb

```
def postcode
    place = Place.where(postcode: postcode).first
    state = place.state.name
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render json: { state: state } }
    end
end
```

I get this results in console:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    app/controllers/places_controller.rb:4:in `postcode'
    (keeps going the infinite loop...)
```

The line 4 in places_controller is the `place = Place.where(postcode: postcode).first` line.

I don't know what am i doing wrong. Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)` because your action name is `postcode` and your object variable name/method is also named `postcode`.

```
  place = Place.where(postcode: postcode).first
```

The error occurs when you pass in `postcode` attribute because it has the same name as the method/action.

To fix the error, rename the action and route name.

Comment: Very honest mistake. Thanks a lot!